# battery draining when developing

Tags: adb, battery

I am connected via an USB port and have the screen constantly on, with the lowest brightness settings - by using the Lux app, that lowers that below the allowed level, making the screen barely visible.

Nevertheless, the phone is discharging fast.

Nexus 5 stock rom, rooted.

Only one process running in the foreground (an official play store app) which I am trying to automate via adb.

This didn't happen with a chinese MTK tablet, which stayed 100% charged all the time.

What can I do to work around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about underclocking cpu speed. since the device is rooted. or you can check other services that may not be usefull but running background.

if you have busybox or something installed. maybe you can look for processes and their consumption of cpu.